# Only a part of the buttons are displayed on linearlayout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout

I have a linearlayout and there are 3 buttons on each row that are filling the screen in both horizontal and vertical use but the buttons at the very bottom are not displayed as whole. This is the code...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:fillViewport="true" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="15dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="15dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="15dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

        </LinearLayout>




    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

and the main xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: main LinearLayout closing tag left in your code in last

Comment: are you seeing this in preview??

Comment: I see you've forgotten to specify `weightSum` in `LinearLayout`. Define it to `3`

Comment: sorry I forgot to indent last closing tag so my actual code has closing tag and still have the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `ScrollView` does not cooperate with container `CoordinateLayout`.
>   When use `CoordinateLayout` its suggested to use
>   `android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView` for scrolling child
>   views.

Use `android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView` instead of `ScrollView`.

**Here is the working code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:text="1"/>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:text="2"/>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:text="3"/>

            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:text="4"/>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:text="5"/>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:text="6"/>

            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:text="7"/>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:text="8"/>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:text="9"/>

            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:text="10"/>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:text="11"/>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:text="12"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:text="13"/>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:text="14"/>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:text="15"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:text="16"/>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:text="17"/>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:text="18"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:text="19"/>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:text="20"/>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:text="21"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:text="22"/>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:text="23"/>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:text="24"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:text="25"/>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:text="26"/>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:text="27"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Comment: Didn't work. Still looks like on the left side. I put marginBottom on the last buttons but I don't like it. Is there another way doing that?

Comment: are you placing this layout inside another layout?

Comment: It is one of the pages of a viewpager. Do you think that is the problem?

Comment: post the container layout

Comment: added the xml of the container

Comment: Seems OK. Can you please try with `NestedScrollView` intsead of `ScrollView`.?

Comment: Wow that worked thanks... Can you explain me why it worked?

Comment: I think `scrollview` does not fit with container `CoordinateLayout`. When use `CoordinateLayout` its suggested to use `android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView` for scrolling view.

Comment: The ScrollView does not cooperate with the CoordinatorLayout.

Comment: I have updated my answer. If it helps to resolve your problem then please accept this answer. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fillViewport="true" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                >

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                >

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                >

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                >

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                >

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                >

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                >

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                >

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                >

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

            </LinearLayout>






        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing closing Tag at last for `Linear Layout`. Close the tag.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Sorry I didnt see that I forgot to copy the last part of the code but this was my actual code so tags are closed. I still have the problem.

Comment: @gunessun The buttons at bottom are showing to me. What is the issue ?

Comment: Only half of the bottom buttons are showing to me, scrollview doesn't go further.

Comment: @gunessun It's showing to me all the way to bottom total of 27 buttons 9 rows and it's scrollable. Add this `android:scrollbars="vertical"` to `Scroll View`.

Answer (score 0):

try this code,it must work.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:fillViewport="true" ><LinearLayout

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

        </LinearLayout>




    </LinearLayout>
```